# Caching this when using John Resig's javascript inheritance

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, inheritance

I use [John Resig's javascript inheritance pattern](http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-javascript-inheritance/) ([better formatted version](https://gist.github.com/jhbsk/4380541)) in several projects.

Using this pattern, I can call one class method from inside another like `this.otherMethod()`.

However, my class methods often include code that has it's own scope with it's own `this` defined such as jQuery methods like ajax success handlers or `$.each`.

Something like this would be typical:

```
 var AppWidget = Class.extend({
    /**
     * Initialize and set any defaults
     */
    init: function(options) {

        var _this = this;
        var defaults = {
        };
        _this.options = $.extend(true, defaults, options);
        return _this;
    },

    /**
     * Do something involving ajax
     */
    someAjaxyFunction:function(){
        var _this = this;

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "page.php",
            data: dataString,
            success: function(data) {
                _this.someFollowupFunction(data)
            }
        }); 
    },

    /**
     * Do some followup work
     */
    someFollowupFunction:function(data){
        var _this = this;
        $.each(data,function () {
            _this.someOtherFunction(this);
        });
    },

    /**
     * Do some other work
     */
    someOtherFunction:function(thing){
        var _this = this;
         //...
    }
});
```

And it would be called like:

```
var widget = new AppWidget();
widget.someAjaxyFunction();
```

This works, however, I would like to know if there is a better way to handle caching `this` to be used in the methods. Adding `var _this = this;` to the top of every class method works but is quite cumbersome and I often forget it when coding a new method.

Is there some clever way to make the `_this` automatically available within all class methods, or some better way for the method to reference the class other than the `this` keyword?

Comment: binding `this` is not an option? Can you (if you like) change the way Class.extend works, or are you looking for a workaround for the implementation?

Comment: @Icepickle for sure, Im open to modifying any part of it.

Comment: I was thinking, one could theoretically expand the functions to 'inject' a _this variable (which would entail serializing the functions, and then adding a `new Function` with the arguments declaration and the new `_this` var. However, I can think of quite a few downsides to this approach (-> no chance for minification, use strict would throw an error). Another possible option could be to send a new argument that would be your context (ie always the first or the last), which wouldn't be error prone to compressing, but could have some downsides as well, depends what you want...

Comment: An example from the second approach could be something like this: [callback with call](https://jsfiddle.net/Icepickle/cbwd4bp6/1/) or [direct callback](https://jsfiddle.net/Icepickle/cbwd4bp6/2/) (Theoretically you could do a similar test like the _super test and inject _this only when it is actually used)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned that you are open for modifying the `Class.extend` implementation from John, you could theoretically inject the `_this` variable as a function parameter.

This of course heavily depends on how much changes you wish to make on your current running code.

In my example, I added the `_this` parameter to the function argument list, as the first parameter for all functions. This would change your example class in the following way (the full example can be found in the snippet below):

```
var Example = Class.extend({
  method: function(_this, timeout) {
    // some code
  },
  callback: function(_this, arg1) {
    // some code
  }
});

var example = new Example();
example.method(5);
```

As you can see, _this is now always the first argument. However, how you call the methods in the class doesn't change, you can still call `example.method(15)` which would call `method` with a prefilled _this argument (which is assigned to the argument list through the `Class.extend` method)

This would still allow you to use the `this._super()` implementation, which would even supply the correct callback (nl: the one to the deriving class afterwards, like for example here)

```
var Sample = Example.extend({
    method: function(_this, timeout) {
    this._super(timeout);
    console.log('I was called from sample');
  },
  callback: function(_this) {
    console.log('I am supplied from Sample');
  }
});

var sample = new Sample();
sample.method(10);
```

The changes required for John's code (originally from [John's blog](http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-javascript-inheritance/), deeper discussed inside [Secrets of a JavaScript Ninja](https://www.manning.com/books/secrets-of-the-javascript-ninja)), would be something similar to this:

```
/* Simple JavaScript Inheritance
 * By John Resig http://ejohn.org/
 * MIT Licensed.
 */
// Inspired by base2 and Prototype
(function(){
  var initializing = false, fnTest = /xyz/.test(function(){xyz;}) ? /\b_super\b/ : /.*/;
  // The base Class implementation (does nothing)
  this.Class = function(){};

  function convertArgumentsToArray( args ) {
    return Array.prototype.slice.apply( args );
  }

  // Create a new Class that inherits from this class
  Class.extend = function(prop) {
    var _super = this.prototype;

    // Instantiate a base class (but only create the instance,
    // don't run the init constructor)
    initializing = true;
    var prototype = new this();
    initializing = false;


    // Copy the properties over onto the new prototype
    for (var name in prop) {
      // Check if we're overwriting an existing function
      prototype[name] = typeof prop[name] == "function" && 
        typeof _super[name] == "function" && fnTest.test(prop[name]) ?
        (function(name, fn){
          return function() {
            var tmp = this._super;

            // Add a new ._super() method that is the same method
            // but on the super-class
            this._super = _super[name];

            // The method only need to be bound temporarily, so we
            // remove it when we're done executing
            var ret = fn.apply(this, [this].concat( convertArgumentsToArray( arguments ) ));        
            this._super = tmp;

            return ret;
          };
        })(name, prop[name]) :
        (function(fn) {
          return function() {
            var ret = fn.apply(this, [this].concat( convertArgumentsToArray( arguments ) ));
            return ret;
          }
        })(prop[name]);
    }

    // The dummy class constructor
    function Class() {
      // All construction is actually done in the init method
      if ( !initializing && this.init )
        this.init.apply(this, arguments);
    }

    // Populate our constructed prototype object
    Class.prototype = prototype;

    // Enforce the constructor to be what we expect
    Class.prototype.constructor = Class;

    // And make this class extendable
    Class.extend = arguments.callee;

    return Class;
  };
})();
```

For which the main change would be that the `this` context gets injected into the parameter list automatically.

An optimization which could still be made, would be to check if the `_this` variable is defined in the argument list, as for the moment, if you have any arguments, you should always add the `_this` parameter as the first parameter.

A full working example you can see here in the code snippet, or on jsfiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Icepickle/cbwd4bp6/3/)

```js
/* Simple JavaScript Inheritance
     * By John Resig http://ejohn.org/
     * MIT Licensed.
     */
// Inspired by base2 and Prototype
(function(){
  var initializing = false, fnTest = /xyz/.test(function(){xyz;}) ? /\b_super\b/ : /.*/;
  // The base Class implementation (does nothing)
  this.Class = function(){};

  function convertArgumentsToArray( args ) {
    return Array.prototype.slice.apply( args );
  }

  // Create a new Class that inherits from this class
  Class.extend = function(prop) {
    var _super = this.prototype;

    // Instantiate a base class (but only create the instance,
    // don't run the init constructor)
    initializing = true;
    var prototype = new this();
    initializing = false;


    // Copy the properties over onto the new prototype
    for (var name in prop) {
      // Check if we're overwriting an existing function
      prototype[name] = typeof prop[name] == "function" && 
        typeof _super[name] == "function" && fnTest.test(prop[name]) ?
        (function(name, fn){
        return function() {
          var tmp = this._super;

          // Add a new ._super() method that is the same method
          // but on the super-class
          this._super = _super[name];

          // The method only need to be bound temporarily, so we
          // remove it when we're done executing
          var ret = fn.apply(this, [this].concat( convertArgumentsToArray( arguments ) ));        
          this._super = tmp;

          return ret;
        };
      })(name, prop[name]) :
      (function(fn) {
        return function() {
          var ret = fn.apply(this, [this].concat( convertArgumentsToArray( arguments ) ));
          return ret;
        }
      })(prop[name]);
    }

    // The dummy class constructor
    function Class() {
      // All construction is actually done in the init method
      if ( !initializing && this.init )
        this.init.apply(this, arguments);
    }

    // Populate our constructed prototype object
    Class.prototype = prototype;

    // Enforce the constructor to be what we expect
    Class.prototype.constructor = Class;

    // And make this class extendable
    Class.extend = arguments.callee;

    return Class;
  };
})();


var Example = Class.extend({
  method: function(_this, timeout) {
    console.log('timeout defined is ' + timeout);
    setTimeout(function() {
      _this.callback( 15 );
    }, timeout);
  },
  callback: function(_this, arg1) {
    console.log('callback from _this argument, current context: ', this);
    console.log(_this === this);
    console.log(arg1 === 15);
  }
});

var Sample = Example.extend({
  method: function(_this, timeout) {
    this._super(timeout);
    console.log('I was called from sample');
  },
  callback: function(_this) {
    console.log('I am supplied from Sample');
  }
});

var example = new Example();
example.method(5);

var sample = new Sample();
sample.method(10);
```

Comment: Reminds me of python and exactly what I was looking for, thank you.